# Kotlin get property in the same order they are declared

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I have found some articles on getting properties in Kotlin, but not really something on getting properties in their declared order.

So for now I have created an annotation and used it to declare the order of the properties

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY)
annotation class Pos(val value: Int)

data class ClassWithSortedProperties(
    @Pos(1) val b: String,
    @Pos(2) val a: String = "D",
    @Pos(3) val c: String) {

    class PropertyWithPosition(val pos: Int, val value: String)

    fun toEdifact() = this.javaClass.kotlin.declaredMemberProperties
        .map {
            // Get the position value from the annotation
            val pos = (it.annotations.find { it is Pos } as Pos).value
            // Get the property value
            val value = it.get(this)
            PropertyWithPosition(pos, value.toString())
        }
        .sortedBy { it.pos }
        .joinToString(separator = ":") { it.value }
        .trim(':')
}
```

Is there a better way to get the properties in their declared order?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Easier way would be to read properties from the constructor:

```
 ClassWithSortedProperties::class.
         primaryConstructor?.
         parameters?.
         forEachIndexed { i, property ->
      println("$i $property")
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class Test() {
    val b = "b"
    val a = "a"
    val c = "c"
}

fun main() {
    val fields = Test::class.java.declaredFields
    val orderById = fields.withIndex().associate { it.value.name to it.index }
    val sorted = Test::class.declaredMemberProperties.sortedBy { orderById[it.name] }
}
```

In the `sorted` collection you will get the ordered properties in the same way as they are declared

Answer (score 1):

Data classes generate methods for [destructuring declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html#data-classes-and-destructuring-declarations).

If you know exactly how many fields there are, you can get by without reflection but it will require verbose "boilerplate" code:

```
val item = ClassWithSortedProperties("Z", "X", "C")
val (v1, v2, v3) = item  // destructure (assign to multiple variables)
val listOfProperties = listOf(v1, v2, v3)  // list of all fields

// you can also get a single item at given position:
val secondProperty = item.component2()
```