# kotlin + get all component / members from class (object) with its original order

Tags: kotlin

Im trying to get all `memberProperties` of a `class`. I'm using bellow code

```
for (props in SomeClass::class.memberProperties） {
    //do something with the props
}
```

I can get all the members, but the sequence that I get is ignoring the original member/property's order, instead it automatically ordering it by alphabet (a-z)

For example, If I declare my class as

```
class foo(b:String, a:String, c:String)
```

when I print all of its properties, I would get `a,b,c` rather than `b,a,c`

is there any way for me to iterate all members of a class and maintain it's original order / sequence?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin get property in the same order they are declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51687098/kotlin-get-property-in-the-same-order-they-are-declared)

Comment: @Mafor I tried it, but I can't find `primaryConstructor` under the `class`. I don't know why

Comment: @Mark, I just tried it with your class and it is working with the accepted answer from the question mentioned by @ Mafor. Please check again.